# Get relationship (friend, friend of friend) between two Facebook ids by facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-friends

How can I check for the relation between two facebook ids.? i.e friend, friend of friend or there is no relation. By fql or graph api methods(anything).

I know how to get the friend list, mutual friends of facebook id. But I want a proper method which can give the relation between two Facebook ids. I have Googled a lot but didn't get anything related to my problem.

Comment: I have given solution after research and it is working. Hence accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution by checking with fql queries.

```
//$target_id=id of user to check relationship
//$source_id=logged in user

    $query="SELECT uid, name, work FROM user WHERE uid IN 
    (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = $target_id AND uid2=$source_id)
     ORDER BY name";

    $user_info=$this->facebook->api(array('method'=>'fql.query',
                                'query'=>$query));


    if(!empty($user_info)) 
    {
          $degree='friend';
    }
    else {
        $query="SELECT uid, name, work FROM user WHERE uid IN 
       (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = $target_id) AND uid2=$source_id) 
        ORDER BY name";

       $user_info=$this->facebook->api(array('method'=>'fql.query',
                                    'query'=>$query));

    // we can check friend-of-friend for app user friends

       if(!empty($user_info)) {
           $degree='friend-of-friend'; 
       }
    else{
    $degree='none';
    }
    }
```

Please answer if anyone knows any simple method.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() AND uid2 = {YOUR_FRIEND2_ID}
```

With this FQL query you can check if give ID is a friend of currently logged in user. It'll return an empty array if given users are not friends. Facebook does not give you friends of a friend, so you can't go beyond the logged in user.

> To read the friend table you need
>   any valid access_token to retrieve friends of the current session user
>
> This is the only user that this table can be queried for, the friends of friends cannot be retrieved.

[Facebook offical documentation on friend FQL table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend/)

Comment: Sorry I can check friend of friend by fql query(app users). I want to check by any simple method. We can get friend of friend which are app users.